# ElasticSearch 2.x exists filter for nested field doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-dsl

I have the following mapping

```
{
  "properties": {
    "restaurant_name": {"type": "string"},
    "menu": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "name": {"type": "string"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to filter all those documents which have optional "menu" field exists

```
GET /restaurnats/_search
{
  "filter": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {"exists" : { "field" : "menu" }}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But, when I try the same query to filter those documents which have "restaurant_name", then it works fine. So why nested field check doesn't work? How to get it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a `nested` query instead:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "query": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "menu",
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "menu"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @val for the solution

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when you invert the logic to **must_not**. In my use case, it returns 0 documents, although there are a lot that are missing the field

Comment: @pmishev feel free to create a new question with your specific problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41262668/elasticsearch-2-4-exists-filter-for-nested-objects-not-working