# Elasticsearch, Exists filter for nested objects not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-dsl

My mapping is:

```
"properties": {
  "user": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "is_active": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "null_value": false
      },
      "username": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  },
```

I want to get all documents that do not have a `user` field.

I tried:

```
GET /index/type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "user"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns all documents.
Based on [ElasticSearch 2.x exists filter for nested field doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40475868/elasticsearch-2-x-exists-filter-for-nested-field-doesnt-work/40479451#40479451), I also tried:

```
GET /index/type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "user",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "user"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns 0 documents.

What is the correct query to get all documents missing the `user` field?

Comment: Can you try to test the existence of the `user.id` field instead? If the parent document has no `user` field, then it will also have no `user.id` field.

Comment: I guess that would work well enough, but it'll miss an edge case where user is set but empty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the correct syntax, it should have been:

```
GET /index/type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "user",
            "query": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "user"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be correct, so +1, but there doesn't seem to be any logic as to why it has to be this way round! There doesn't seem to be anything in the docs as to why it has to be like this.

Comment: I am speachless, thanks for this solution. I will attempt to get this pushed to the official doc here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using the parent of the user, here *obj*

```
GET users/users/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "obj.user"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: user has no parent - it is a field in the document, not in a nested object